# Multiple jQuery Ajax calls using promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I'm slowly getting the hang of using promises but now need to handle multiple promises. This is an extract of my code which has two email inputs in a form, both of which generate promises, and both have to be processed before the form can be submitted. How can I deal with this situation?

```
// checks form submission
$('#ml_doaction').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var isOK = true;
  $('form#volreg :input').each(function(){
    var id = this.id;
    switch(id)
    {
      case 'email_one':
      case 'email_two':
        checkEmailStatus(id, true).then(function(data) {
          if(isOK && data !== false) {
            // submit form
            $('form#volreg').submit();
          }
        });
      break;

      // etc ....
      //other validation functions that set isOK appropriately
    }
  });
});

$('#email').blur(function(){checkEmailStatus('email_one')});
$('#contact_email').blur(function(){checkEmailStatus('email_two')});
function checkEmailStatus(id)
{
  var emailVal = $('#' + id).val();
  var dfd = $.Deferred();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',               
    data:{'checkEmailStatus':emailVal, 'checkList': 'General'},
    url:'/php/ajax/validation-ajax.php',
    success:function(response){
      if(response == 'notinlist') {
        dfd.resolve(false);
      }
      else if(response == 'yesinlist') {  
        dfd.resolve(true);
      }
    },
  });
  return dfd.promise();
}
```

Comment: @Taplar: Edited!

Comment: Side note, if your response can only be those two strings, then your bottom success could be shortened to `dfd.resolve(response == 'yesinlist')`.  Also please explicitly state what your problem is in the question.  You left that part out.

Comment: @Taplar: My problem is how to deal with multiple promises when all have to be processed before the form can be submitted.

Comment: So edit your question and say that, :)

Answer (score 1):

You use the `Promise.all` function

```
 var promises = [];
 $('form#volreg :input').each(function(){
    var id = this.id;
    switch(id)
    {
      case 'email_one':
      case 'email_two':
        promises.push(checkEmailStatus(id, true));
      break;

      // etc ....
      //other validation functions that set isOK appropriately
    }
  });

    Promise.all(promises).then(function(values) {
      var isData = true;
       $.each(values,function(v) {
           if(v == false) {isData = false;
           break;}
        })
       if(isOK && isData !== false) {
            // submit form
            $('form#volreg').submit();
          }
    });
```

Comment: Not sure where to put your code. In the switch case?

Comment: in the `case 'email_two':` you remove the promise resolve and push the promise to the pormise array, after the loop you call `promise.all`

Comment: Very many thanks for the detailed example. But is there not a typo in the each loop? Better as:
    if(v == false) {
        isData = false;
        break;
     }

Comment: ya sorry, ma bad